# bm-800 setup without external devices

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, microphone

I have a BM-800 microphone and I'm using sound-card. but I want to know is there any possibility to use microphone without any phantom power and sound-card ? version 20.04. device - Lenovo ideapad 310.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the BM-800 you're talking about?

[image: BM-800]

Doesn't require phantom power. However it does require a soundcard or an external interface. The internal mic jack on the computer / iPad / whatever should do just fine for some purposes. Please see what **Tetsujin** tells in the comments below!

Now with your system that is a bit of a problem, as it only has a mic/headset combo jack. So unless you use a Bluetooth headset or find a splitter adapter, it's either or.

Best option is still an external interface. Something like Focusrite Scarlett (no, I don't own one) is a sound investment, and you can get a 2nd hand one for surprisingly decent price.

Comment: They do actually need a bias voltage - low, maybe 1.5V will just about get a signal out of them; but they really work best on 'proper' 48v phantom power. Unfortunately they are supplied with a stoopid mini jack, so you need to not only get a decent USB mic preamp, but also an XLR/XLR cable. They're really quite surprisingly 'not awful' when wired up properly;) [source of info: I bought one of these things a couple of years ago, for a whole 12 quid brand new, so I could answer questions about them on Sound Design.] I could have bought another 190 of them for the price of my actual vocal mic ;))

Comment: Also, though they "will work" on a bias voltage from a PC mic jack, they're actually low impedance, not high, so that degrades the sonic experience still further. They *really* need a low impedance dedicated mic preamp. [None of this is ever mentioned in the advertising.] :\

Comment: LOL :-D I stand corrected! I've actually heard the exact same "surpringsingly not awful" before, was considering buying a couple, but got a good deal from Lewitt so... but you just got me interested again :-D In any case it might complement well the pair of Singstars I bought for a fiver - hey, they ain't no such thing as a "bad mic", just incorrect choices :-D I've got ADA8200 hooked up with Apollo Quad... whaddyathink, might that work?

Comment: tbh, I've never used anything made by Behringer… call it bias, though even the BBC use their high end stuff these days [I was shocked when I first saw one at the radio station my friend works in - he apologised for it & said "It's not all that bad, considering" ;) At home these days I just use a Line6 UX-2, it's all I need. The myriad different badged versions of the BM7/800/0 probably have poor QA, so while they are 'not awful' & I do use that term advisedly;) I wouldn't hold much hope for them making a good stereo pair… though for under a 'pony' [look it up;) you could give it a try.

Comment: For the OP @WhiteShadow - this was the QA I tried to cover the basics on Sound Design - https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon

Comment: Dang - here I was hoping... nah, got 2 pairs of small diags for stereo :-) At this point it's just for curiosity, them's BM:s cheap enuff for "let's see what this does". Even those bloody home karaoke mics are useful, they do interesting things for distorted guitars when paired well :-) You mean there are ppl who _don't_ have Beh bias?!? My first UX-2 got damaged by a power spike, something burned. Replaced with a 2nd hand one, dumped it when finally realized that all my mixes are wonky simply cuz there's 6dB difference between the channels! Good interface once you learn it, methinks :-)

Comment: Never had any issues with the UX2 at all. Had one since they first came out [05-ish?] - never had need to replace it yet. I don't use much of the modelling in it, run it pretty flat, really just as an i/o.

Comment: Mine dated back abt there as well. 10 years of use w/o a glitch, that's why I went for the same. Still weighing the options whether there's any point getting a third one :-) The culprit was the house circuit; breaked my backup drive hooked up on the same USB hub too :-( I had one prob - with W10 wouldn't work through a powered hub anymore. Win7 had no issues.